# Simplifying propositional formula

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

[a ^ ¬(b^c^d)] V [a^b^ ¬(c^d)] V [¬a^b^¬(c^d)] V [a^b^¬c^d] V [a^b^c^¬d]

=[a^¬(b^c^d)] V [b^¬(c^d)] V [a^b^¬c^d] V [a^b^c^¬d]

=[a^¬(b^c^d)] V [b^¬c] V [b^¬d] V [a^b^¬c^d] V [a^b^c^¬d]

=[a^¬b] V [a^¬c] V [a^¬d] V [b^¬c] V [b^¬d] V [a^b^¬c^d] V [a^b^c^¬d]

=[a^¬b] V [a^¬c] V [a^¬d] V [b^¬c] V [b^¬d] V [a^¬c] V [b^¬d]

= [a^¬b] V [a^¬c] V [a^¬d] V [b^¬c] V [b^¬d{
( the answer is supposed to be [b^¬c] V [b^¬d] V [a^¬c] + [a^¬d]

Comment: What is the difference between $ab'(cd)$ and $ab'cd$? And $+$ is xor, so you're using ring notation? or $+$ is or?

Comment: And what is $'ab'(cd)$? The not before $a$ is weird ?

Comment: a ^ b ^ ~ [c^d], im sry i didnt know how else to write the boolean expressions =/

Comment: You mean `a \land b \land \lnot(c \land d)` which gives $a \land b \land \lnot(c \land d)$ between dollar signs? Use `\land`, `\lor`, `\lnot` for logical symbols and correct braces.

Comment: i changed it to set notations

Comment: Please learn to use MathJax!

Comment: I tried to edit your question using MathJax, but there seems to be some ambiguities, and perhaps your difficulty lies in some wrong association of terms which result from that. Right in the first line, you have $\wedge$ and $\vee$ mixed up, without parentheses, and you even miss an operation after the second occurrence of $b$, where you have $$\cdots a \wedge b \neg(c \wedge d) \vee \cdots$$

Comment: i tried putting everything in a neater way but it still looks confusing... and i don't know how to use MathJax =/

Answer (score 3):

Like Vineet, I'll take the starting expression as:

$a(bcd)'+ ab(cd)'+a'b(cd)'+abc'd +abcd'$

Now, assuming you copied the starting expression correctly from the book, the 'supposed' answer $bc'+bd'+ac'+ad'$ is incorrect:

Take $A=C=D=T$, and $B=F$

Then the original expression evaluates to $T$ (since $a(bcd)'$ is True)

but the supposed answer evaluates to False

Now, *your* answer of $ab'+ac'+ad'+bc'+bc'$ *is* equivalent to the starting expression (good job!) ... but it can be simplified a little further:

$ab'+ac'+ad'+bc'+bd'=$  ($ad'=abd'+ab'd'$)

$ab'+ac'+abd'+ab'd'+bc'+bd'=$ ($abd'$ gets absorbed by $bd'$, and $ab'd'$ by $ab'$)

$ab'+ac'+bc'+bd'=$ ($ac'=abc'+ab'c'$)

$ab'+abc'+ab'c'+bc'+bd'=$ ($abc'$ gets absorbed by $bc'$, and $ab'c'$ by $ab'$)

$ab'+bc'+bd'$

These last few steps can actually be done immediately using the [Consensus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem):

$xy+x'z+yz=xy+x'z$

That is, from

$ab'+ac'+ad'+bc'+bd'$

we can eliminate $ad'$ as the consensus of $ab'$ and $bd'$, as well as $ac'$ as the consensus of $ab'$ and $bc'$

Another useful principle is:

**Generalized Reduction**

$pq+pq'r=pq+pr$

So, starting at the very beginning:

$a(bcd)'+ ab(cd)'+a'b(cd)'+abc'd +abcd'\overset{DeMorgan}{=}$

$a(b'+c'+d')+ ab(c'+d')+a'b(c'+d')+abc'd +abcd'\overset{Distribution}{=}$

$ab'+ac'+ad'+abc'+abd'+a'bc'+a'bd'+abc'd+abcd'\overset{Absorption}{=}$

$ab'+ac'+ad'+a'bc'+a'bd'\overset{Reduction}{=}$

$ab'+ac'+ad'+bc'+bd'\overset{Consensus}{=}$

$ab'+bc'+bd'$

Answer (score 2):

$[a \wedge ¬(b\wedge c \wedge d)] \vee [a\wedge b \wedge ¬(c\wedge d)] \vee [¬a\wedge b \wedge ¬(c\wedge d)] \vee [a\wedge b\wedge ¬c\wedge d] \vee [a\wedge b\wedge c\wedge ¬d]$

I will be taking a CS approach. Assume $\wedge$ as AND $\vee $ as OR and $¬ $ as NOT.
Rewriting,

$a (bcd)'+ ab(cd)'+a'b(cd)'+abc'd +abcd'$

$a(b'+c'+d')+ab(c'+d')+abc'd+abcd'$  (Demorgan's Law)

$ab'+ac'+ad'+abc'+abd'+abc'd+abcd'$

$ab'+ac'+ad'+abd'+abc'(1+d)+abcd'$

$ab'+ac'+ad'(1+b)+abc'(1+d)+abcd'$

$ab'+ac'+ad'+abc'+abcd'$

$ab'+ac'+ad'(1+bc)+abc'$

$ab'+ac'+ad'+abc'$

$ab'+ac'(1+b)+ad'$

$ab'+ac'+ad'$

$a(b'+c'+d')$ (Demorgan's Law)

$a(bcd)'$

$\boxed{a\wedge ¬(b \wedge c \wedge d)}$

Hope I didn't commited any mistake.

Comment: actually that's a CS- logic related question, i thought since this follows the same logic as predicate calculus, it wouldn't really change anything but the answer given is supposed to be[ [b^¬c] V [b^¬d] V [a^¬c] + [a^¬d], if u draw a k-map, the answer simplifies to this

Comment: That cannot be the correct answer, since with $a=d=F$, and $b=c=T$, the original expression is True (since $a'b(cd)'$ is True), but your last expression is False.  Indeed, you forgot to copy the $a'b(cd)'$ term right at the beginning when you did DeMorgan